# How to disable netlinks from Linux kernel for link state change

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, netlink

I have any app A which is listening on netlink events for interface from kernel ( Link state change etc).

I have another app B which does ifconfig up/ down. At this moment I don't want App A to get netlinks notified from kernel. How do I mask netlink state change for a particular interface in Linux ?

Any info on this would be of good help.